# What is wrong with angular component "bindings" parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have an angular component that I want to include in my page.
everything works if I comment/remove **bindings** parameter in this component... Why?

```
(function () {

    angular.module('app').component('detailsComponent1', {
        templateUrl: '/RealSuiteApps/RealForm/-1/Details/Component1',
        restrict: 'E',
        bindings: {
            value: "Component1"
        },
        controllerAs: 'cm',
        controller: function () {
            this.message = 'Hello from component1';
        }
    });

})();
```

If I want to use **binding** parameter, I get an error:

[image]

that links to: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/iscp?p0=detailsComponent1&p1=value&p2=Component1&p3=controller%20bindings%20definition

What does it mean ??

Thanks.

Comment: So? The template comes from MVC call, it has nothing to do with the question. I said, everything works if I remove bindings...

Comment: remove `restrict: 'E',` as well. Error is because of `value: "Component1"` make it like `value: @Component1` or `value: =Component1`

Answer (score 2):

Well, The error is coming because of **Invalid Isolate scope**

When declaring isolate scope the scope definition object must be in specific format which starts with mode character **(@&=<)**, after which comes an optional ?, and it ends with an optional local name.

Please find the reference link here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/iscp

Plus, you have some discarded directive property inside component.

> restrict (restricted to elements for component)

Please find documentation for component here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Hope it helps you!

Cheers